# ASP.Net MVC 3 validation on AjaxForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, ajaxform

I have an ajax form on razor view engine. For validation i use dataanotation classes. Validation work fine when user submit the form, validation messages work fine.
The problem is, validation wont work on keyup or blur events.

How can i activate validation without submit on ajaxform(ajax.beginform)

Here is my view code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,       
        UpdateTargetId = "employeeDetail", HttpMethod = "Post", OnComplete = "Complete", 
        Confirm = "Confirm?" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Email)
    <span style="float:right"><input type="submit" class="tableGenelButton" id="submitButton" value="Kaydet" /></span>
}
```

Model:

```
  [RequiredWithMessage]
  [Display(Name = "E-Mail")]
  public string Email { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

Ok, apparently you're using `Ajax.BeginForm` which uses MicrosoftAjax in stead of jQuery (I didn't realize that before). This one needs some extra work to enable client side validation:

You need

```
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

Somewhere in your page, and also links to `MicrosoftAjax.js`, `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` and `MicrosoftMvcValidation.js`

Here's a link that might be interesting for you:

> [ASP.NET MVC Client Side Validation With Ajax.BeginForm](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2010/07/18/asp-net-mvc-client-side-validation-with-ajax-beginform.aspx)

---

To enable client side validation for a custom validation attribute (I guess `[RequiredWithMessage]` is one of those), you have to implement the [IClientValidatable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

Here is an article that explains how to do that:

> [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: The problem is not in custom validation attribute. I also get the same problem when i use default [Required] dataanotation class.

Comment: @user: [Required] should work out of the box in MVC 3. Make sure you have a setting `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />` under `appSettings` in your web.config file. And of course you also need to have a reference to jquery and jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobstrusive (in case `UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled` is true) in your view.

Comment: i did everything you told before. I add all refs. in to layout page also add "ClientValidationEnabled" setting to web.config.

Comment: Aah, I see now you're using `Ajax.BeginForm`. I thought you were using `Html.BeginForm`. I don't have experience with Ajax.BeginForm and client side validation. I know it should work (out of the box) with Html.BeginForm though.

Comment: :D you miss understood me. np thanx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have client side validation [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695186/enable-client-validation-in-razor-views-asp-mvc-3), you will need to call [.validate()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) in the relevant events:

```
$("#theFormToValidate input").blur(function(){
    $("#theFormToValidate").validate();
});
```

and

```
$("#theFormToValidate input").keyup(function(){
    $("#theFormToValidate").validate();
});
```

Comment: These should happen automatically... I think the OP is talking about client side validation for his custom validation attribute (`[RequiredWithMessage]`).