# Validating in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

Hi i am a beginner in MVC i have written code for validating but it is not working can anyone please help me out.
Here is the model code:

```
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Here is the View code:

```
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactDetailSubSections[i].Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ContactDetailSubSections[i].Name)
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is  there validation script in your page?

Comment: Make sure unobtrusive validation is enabled

Comment: yes i have done that. I am validating for length of a string that is working but the required field is not working.

Comment: You should be adding `jquery.validate.min.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` on top of your view

Comment: Here is the bundle.config file i have added all validation scripts
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

Comment: Try replacing `[Required]` with `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Enable Client side validation feature of MVC for standard validation which doesn't require any server side code in controller.

[Enable Client side Validation](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/bcWO151212-How-to-Enable-and-Disable-Client-Side-Validation-in-MVC.html)

[Enable Client side Validation-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695186/enable-client-validation-in-razor-views-asp-mvc-3)

However you also must check ModestState.IsValid() at controller level for better security.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need any of JS libraries for ASP.NET MVC server validation.
Second, you should check in controller, that a model is valid.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    //do something
}
return View(); //you can return view with optional parameters
```

Also, you should check which Method for sending data are you use (POST or GET) and check that this method is used in controller (for sending data always use a POST method).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
       //do something
    }
    return View();
}
```

This is the project for you (Validation.zip): http://sdrv.ms/UP3DIE (I'm using VS 2012)
There is only one field with Required attribute and custom error message (model LocalValidationTestModel). And in the view there are two methods for displaying errors:
@Html.ValidationSummary() and @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.TestField)

All JS scripts and CSS styles are cutted.

Also, why are you using arrays?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reference several files of jquery .
and then in the action ,you must do something ,like this:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid) { //TODO } return View();
```

and the action must add attribute is `[HttpPost]`