# Disable Unobtrusive Validation in MVC ASP.net Project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

I need to remove unobtrusive validation in my ASP.net MVC project because I am dynamically creating drop down lists.

I am attempting to use

```
    @{HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;}
```

but I get the error "HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for ClientValidationEnabled".

Does anyone know how to fix that or perhaps another solution to this problem? I really only need it disabled for one form.

Comment: Try "EnableClientValidation(bool)": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.enableclientvalidation?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Comment: I assume this is in my controller for the view?

Comment: right in the view methinks...  @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); } see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695186/enable-client-validation-in-razor-views-asp-mvc-3

Comment: @(ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = true) is what worked best for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@(ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled = true)